# Channel create name Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I make the channel that is created called for example "**TheRedyYT's Channel**"?

```
addChannel.guild.channels.create(member.user.username, {
            type: 'voice',
            parent: addCategory.id,
            permissionOverwrites: [{
                id: member.id,
                allow: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS', 'MANAGE_ROLES']
            }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the channel named to the executor of the command you can try:

```
addChannel.guild.channels.create(`${member.user.username}'s Channel`, {
        type: 'voice',
        parent: addCategory.id,
        permissionOverwrites: [{
            id: member.id,
            allow: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS', 'MANAGE_ROLES']
        }]
```

I have to assume that `addChannel`, `member` and `addCategory` are already defined.
In the code example above I made a string as the name of the created channel. In this string I used the username of the member as you did, but with the result that you want. For example if I would execute the command the channel would be named `Freem | Jannik's Channel`.